# Best Practise: Is it a good idea to expose a service as public : Angular 9

Tags: angular

This is a best Practise Question for guidance

Typically, when getting data from a Service, I'll inject the service into the ctor as private service, and assign any observable data (from it) to a local property in my component.

My question is... Is it considered "Best Practise" to access a local component property or access a property on a service directly (from my view)?

This would require changing the access modifier of the injected service to public, as I'd want to access the service directly from my view.

I know this will work BUT is this Okay or does it have security implications?

Any advice gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you plan to do with the code.   Once it's compiled to JavaScript, there isn't any sense of public/protected/private anyway.

If you need to use something in a template, or call from an unrelated class, it must be public or you will get a compiler error.

If you want classes that extend your class to be able to call methods directly, they need to be at least protected.

If you don't want even classes that extend your class to have access, make them private.

It doesn't have any security implications.  If someone is using your app, assume its compromised / never trust the client and always validate on the server.

Comment: This question is prompted by the desire to limit the local properties getting data from observables. Its cleaner markup to access a property on a service from my view, and reduces the amount of code in your component. Frankly anything that reduces the amount of code is a good thing. But, I didn't develop Angular and this method is not advocated in the Angular documentation, hence the question.